# Triggering JavaScript events on storefront

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work on [ECWID](https://developers.ecwid.com/api-documentation#change-font). Now I add an option for product called "preorder" should when I make it yes in selection the bottom appear and it works. Then I do this by hand but when the code trigger the option it works as the option in select menu changes but the bottom does not appear. Is triggering JavaScript events not possible in storefront?

For example is did this code in console:

```
$('#ecwid-productoption-131321321-preorder').val('Yes').change();
```

Select happen but none of other events.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking into triggering a `change` event...

Try this:

```
$('#ecwid-productoption-131321321-preorder').val('Yes').trigger('change');
```